# Docker image with multiple databases in CircleCI

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, circleci

I have an app that has multi-tenant architecture and does create a new database via executing shell command calling `exec()` in PHP code. The thing is that because of such a call, I can’t use multiple Docker images for multiple databases.

Right now I have trouble with testing the code on CircleCI as they rely on Docker and I can't find an image that supports multiple databases via env variables. How can I create an additional database, or can I find MySQL or MariaDB Docker image with multiple databases?

I have [cross posted this to CircleCI Discourse](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-can-i-create-multiple-mysql-databases-in-the-same-docker-image/24762).

Comment: Do you need mulitple databases or just multiple schemas?

Comment: multiple databases. actually got it solved here few minutes ago - https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-can-i-create-multiple-mysql-databases-in-the-same-docker-image/24762/3

Comment: oh, wait, are you creating schema from php using command line ? Why ? o_O

Comment: @AlexKapustin you can say so. The second app has migrations to create an empty database, which the first application dump after that and then creates a new database and imports that dump. The logic was written long before, so I cant justify that desicion